# I have to re-download (get latest versions) all of my files from TFS server after reinstalling Visual Studio, really?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I'm not so sure how TFS works to keep all local files in sync with the server's versions. In my case, almost ***all the local files are just up-to-date*** and it would be great if I don't have to re-download all that are already available as latest versions in my local storage.

I had to reinstall Visual Studio after a failure of porting the OS to a new drive. However the local project files are on a different drive which was kept untouched.
After new installation, I can see that all the remote entries are still mapped correctly to the local paths (I don't have to click on the `Not mapped` link as for a completely new machine). However all the files are grayed out and appeared under status of `Not downloaded` but actually they are just up-to-date.

So that means I have to re-download all before working on each project again. Do I have any other options to not have to re-download all the files? This sounds really ridiculous to me. There should be some simpler way, such as instead of downloading, it should somehow check that all the local files are just exactly matched with the corresponding ones on the remote server and simply skip the downloading...

I have GBs of project files on TFS, each time reinstalling Visual Studio will scare me a lot (due to waiting and maybe some possible files missing/corruption)

Comment: That's why people choose to use Git.

Comment: Are you using a local workspace or a server workspace? This should not be a problem with a local workspace.

Comment: @DanielMann I always use local workspace. Actually it's strange that at a time I could see all the file entries ***are not grayed out***, so they looked just like everything is fine. But after trying to update to get a newly added and checked-in folder (from other machine), everything appears grayed out.